# How to prevent pushing loaded class in controller scope CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I writed in Code Igniter:

```
public $settings = array();
public function __construct() {
  $this->load->model('settings');
  $_settings = new Settings;
  $_settings->get();
  foreach ($_settings as $_setting) {
    $this->settings[$_setting->alias] = $_setting->value;
  }
}
```

It makes to me error in (this-load-settings) -> settings already defined in Controller.

Yes, i did define it in public...I want to prevent CI from adding model and other classes to Controller scope after load.
How i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. system/core/Loader.php
2. find $CI->$name
3. comment lines